# Increase object names programmatically C#

Tags: c#, object, textbox, names

I have a textbox for data entry and 10 textboxes for showing data. 10 viewer textboxes are `visible=false` by default. For example when I enter textbox count to be "3" , only 3 textboxes should be visible. (Then I can do whatever I want with those textboxes)

[image: Example]

Here's my code;

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ToString());

SqlCommand pencere = new SqlCommand("select COUNT (distinct(grup)) as ürün from fiyat", conn);
SqlCommand pencereisimleri = new SqlCommand("select distinct(grup) as ürün from fiyat", conn);
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = pencere.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(pencereisimleri);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt1);

List<String> stringArr = new List<String>();

for (int a = 0; a < dt1.Rows.Count; a++)
{
    TextBox[a].Visible = true;
    TextBox[a].Text = "Open Textbox";                    
}
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Instead of hiding the textboxes initially and then showing on the basis of count, why not generate them dynamically n textboxes

Comment: Sorry, i added the code.

Comment: actually if once i can solve this issue, i'll use this code with pictureboxes and panels which is created,arranged and resized before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, if you're going for this, but how about adding the text boxes to a collection, like an array or List?

Example:

```
private List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>();
boxes.Add(textBox1);
boxes.Add(textBox2);
// etc...
```

Then you could use a foreach (or for) loop, to go through your boxes:

```
for (int a = 0; a < dt1.Rows.Count; a++)
{
    boxes[a].Visible = true;
    boxes[a].Text = "Open Textbox";
}
```

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I can help

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = dt1.Rows.Count;

foreach (Control x in this.Controls)
{
    if (count == 0)
       break;

    if (x is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)x).Text = "Open Textbox";
        ((TextBox)x).Visible = true;
        count--;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also work, but bottom is better for me. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can bind visibility to an array

```
Visibility[] tbViz = new Visibility[10];
public Visibility[] TbViz { get { return tbViz; } }
public void UpdateViz(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tbViz.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < num)
            tbViz[i] = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        else
            tbViz[i] = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }

}

Visisbility="{binding path=TbViz[0]}"
```

if winforms same approach

```
public void UpdateViz(int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tbViz.Length; i++)
        tbViz[i].Visisble = (i < num);
}
```